# question about exponential growth using e

Tags: calculus, exponentiation

Advertisers generally assume that the rate at which people hear about a product is proportional to the number of people who have not yet heard about it. Suppose that the size of a community is $15,000$, that to begin with no one has heard about a product, but that after 6 days $1500$ people know about it. How long will it take for $2700$ people to have heard of it?

I came up with formula
$$y=-1+e^{1.219t}$$
and this is right formula from answer
$$y=15000 \left(1-e^{-0.018t} \right)$$
both of them increase in proportional manner and reach about $1500 $ after $6$ days. But when it comes to calculating time for $2700$ people, the answer is different.

I drew both graphs on Desmos and this is what I got:
[image]

So I just assume my formula doesn't actually has any converging limit which is, in this case $15000$. However, I am curious if my formula can be still valid even if there is no such limit point?

Comment: The "limit point" is the total number of people(size of a community). If there is no "limit point", then the assumption that "the rate at which people hear about a product is proportional to the number of people who have not yet heard about it" just doesn't make sense.

Comment: What answer do you get and what is it supposed to be? Could it be that the value $0.018$ you have used is not very accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to the given question, your formula is not valid because it does not correctly represent the property "the rate at which people hear about a product is proportional to the number of people who have not yet heard about it".

Looking at your formula, we have $y = -1 + e^{1.219t}$, and the rate of change is given by $\dot{y} = 1.219 e^{1.219t} = 1.219(y + 1)$. If we try to interpret that in the context of the problem, your formula satisfies the property "the rate at which people hear about a product is proportional to one more than the number of people who have already heard about it".

This is a valid alternative model, although it has issues - as you noted, it will grow without bound even though we only have a finite community of people to reach.

To get the answer given, you would start by noting that if $y$ people in the community *have* heard about the product, that means that $15000-y$ people *haven't* heard about it. So "the rate at which people hear about a product" needs to be proportional to this value, i.e. $\dot{y} \propto 15000 - y$, or in other words $\dot{y} = k(15000 - y)$ for some constant $k$. We can then integrate that and use the two given points to get the formula for $y$ given in the answer.